# Interpret the result when there is significant correlation but insignificant difference

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, t-test, interpretation, spearman-rho

**Problem**

I have to find out correlation between two variables, variable A and variable B. Let's assume, variable A represents the time spent for study and variable B represents students CGPA. I have found significant positive correlation between variable A and B. To compare between students, I have divided them into  groups - Group P and Group Q. The top and bottom one third percentile of the time spent for study represents Group P and Q respectively. Since there was positive correlation of CGPA with time spent for study, I expected that Group P and Q students will have significant different CGPA. However, I did not find any significant difference (0.05 < p < 0.1) between group P and Q of students.

**My Question**

How should I interpret the result when there is significant positive correlation but there is no significant difference between the two groups of students CGPA?

**Note:** I know that having significant correlation between A and B does not ensure that there will have significant difference between Group P and Q students CGPA.

**Please, feel free to ask questions to understand the problem, if you have any.**

Comment: When you finally run a hypothesis test, what are you testing?

Comment: I am testing whether there is any impact of "time spent for study" on students academic result.

Comment: So didn’t you test the correlation and find that it’s there?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I did not find any significant difference (0.05 < p < 0.1) between group P and Q of students.

Comment: I would say that the test that counts is testing the correlation. Testing P vs Q introduces artificial grouping. The correlation test considers your data on the continuum on which your populations exist.